# How to avoid security certificate errors/warnings raised by excel when retrieving data using querytables

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

How can I avoid security certificate errors/warnings raised by excel when retrieving data using querytables from a server that has multiple certificates (we do not wish to revert to the use of ActiveX components).

Our servers are using [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) and publish several certificates. The first time a querytable is executed excel reports that the certificate does not match the server and therefore cannot be trusted. On OSX the user can opt to 'always trust' the certificate and no longer gets the warning/error. How can I do this on Windows?

When I accept the certificate everything works fine until I close the Excel application.

Comment: I found this [KB813618](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813618) article. Although it dates back from 2006, I believe there is no way of getting around this error message easily.

Comment: Does anyone know how to configure the Certificate Manager (certmgr.msc) in order to trust the certificate and ignore the error/warning.